# Collection of objects added as particle to a Plane not getting projected within the Plane

Tags: rendering, mesh, objects

[image]

I added a particle property to a plane. I added a collection of 26 objects to particle system and attached it to particle property of a Plane. I was expecting all the objects to be displayed over the plane. But I am seeing that many of the objects are getting displayed out the surface of the plane. The screenshot is added for further clarity. I am a newbie to Blender, kindly excuse my novice writing and please ask for more information if the question is not clear to anyone. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem has to do with the way you created your letters. I'm guessing you added a Text object, converted to a mesh and then separated by loose parts. The problem with this is the whole text object is considered to have one origin point that stays the same for all the individual letters after they have been separated.

In the image below, you can see that no matter what letter object I pick, the origin point is still the same. Also notice how the offset of the particles corresponds somewhat to the offset of the each letter from the origin point.

[image: Origin1]

The solution then, is to reset the origins for each letter back to the center of the object. Select a letter and pick **Object > Set Origin > Origin To Geometry**. Do this for each letter. To make it faster, you can do it for one letter, and repeat for the rest, by selecting them one by one and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

[image: Origin2]

If you want to make sure the origin is at the bottom of the letters (so the particles don't appear "halfway through" the plane), you can be a bit more specific and (in edit mode) select a bottom face (or combination of faces) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select "Cursor to Selected". This will place the 3D cursor in the middle of the face(s) you selected.

[image: Origin3]

From here, go back to Object mode, and select  **Object > Set Origin > Origin To 3D Cursor**. This is a more involved process though, as you will have to do this manually for each letter.

[image: Origin4]

Comment: Thanks Chris :) this will help.